# Show $\|Tf\|_2 \leq \epsilon \|f\|_2+C_\epsilon\|f\|_1$ for a compact operator $T:L^2(0,1)\to L^2(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, compact-operators

$T:L^2(0,1)\to L^2(0,1)$, is a compact operator.
Show that
$$ 
\forall \epsilon>0, \exists C_\epsilon>0; \forall f \in  L^2(0,1), \|Tf\|_2 \leq \epsilon \|f\|_2+C_\epsilon\|f\|_1.
$$

where the $\|f\|_2,\|f\|_1$is the $p-$norm.

We have the consequence that if a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $L^2(0,1)$ satisfies
$$
\|f_n\|_1 \to 0, \|f_n\|_2=1(n\geq1)
$$
then $f_n \to 0$ weakly in $L^2(0,1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose this is false. Then  there exists $\epsilon >0$ and a sequence $(f_n)$ such that   $\|Tf_n\|_2 >\epsilon \|f_n\|_2 +n\|f_n||_1$. Let $g_n=\frac {f_n} {\|f_n\|_2}$. Then $\|g_n\|_2=1$ and $\|g_n\|_1 \leq \frac 1 n \frac {\|Tf_n\|_2} {\|f_n\|_2}$. Since $T$ is bounded it follows that $\|g_n\|_1  \to 0$. Hence $g_n \to 0$ weakly. But $T$ is compact, so $Tg_n \to 0$ in the norm. But $\epsilon <\|Tg_n\|_2$, a contradiction.